# How to ad something every third post django

Tags: python, django, banner

how to put one banner in every third post by one

[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFzBs.png)

```
def all_ads(request):
all_ads = CreateNewAdvert.objects.filter(is_active=True)
all_ads_list = list()
banner = Banners.objects.all()
counter = 0
for i in all_ads:
    if len(all_ads_list) % 3 == 0:
            all_ads_list.append(i)
            all_ads_list = list()
            all_ads_list.append(banner[counter])
    print i
paginator = Paginator(all_ads, 10)  # Show 25 contacts per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'all_ads': all_ads_paginated,
}
return context
```

**need to get this:**
post 1,
post 2,
post 3,
banner 1, post 4,
post 5,
post 6,
banner 2

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: currently you are just checking if the length of the whole list is dividable by three. If you want to check the current iteration you need to structure your code a bit different.  Think about what you want to achieve and go back by building a simple working structure

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_ads(request):
all_ads = CreateNewAdvert.objects.filter(is_active=True)

paginator = Paginator(sort_adds(all_ads), 10)  # Show 25 contacts per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    all_ads_paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'all_ads': all_ads_paginated,
}
return context
```

result

```
def sort_adds(obj):
sell_adds_list = list()
banner = Banners.objects.all()
counter = 0
adds_counter = 0
for i in obj:
    sell_adds_list.append(i)
    adds_counter += 1
    if adds_counter % 3 == 0:
        if not counter > len(banner):
            sell_adds_list.append(banner[counter])
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass
return sell_adds_list
```